# Bash Move Files, Override if Source is Larger File Size

Tags: bash, mv

I would like to move files from directory A to directory B.
I would like to override existing files only, if the source file has a larger file size than the destination file, otherwise skip this file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: In general, i would recomend to use something else than bash for this task. Most *nix systems having bash, also offer "native" support for script based languages like python or perl, each offering an easier interface for getting file information and then do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

@axiac mentioned that `stat` is more efficient than `wc`, so I changed my answer.

You can use `stat` or `wc` to compare the sizes of the two files as shown below.

```
my_mv () {
    file1_path=$1
    file2_path=$2
    file1_size=$(stat -f "%z" $file1_path)
    file2_size=$(stat -f "%z" $file2_path)
    #file1_size=$(wc -c $file1_path | awk '{print $1}')
    #file2_size=$(wc -c $file2_path | awk '{print $1}')
    if [ "$file1_size" -gt "$file2_size" ]; then
        mv $file1_path $file2_path
    else
        echo "Operation Aborted: \"$file1_path\" is not larger than \"$file2_path\""
    fi
}
```

Put this function to your .bashrc/.zshrc, this function is used in the same way as `mv`.

Usage:

```
my_mv path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

Comment: `wc` reads the file and counts its bytes. But there is no need for such an effort. The size of a file is known and can be determined without reading its content. Use `stat`.

Comment: Not sure what the `stat -f "%z" $file1_path` is about. The `-f` flag reports on the filesystem rather than the file itself.

_Edit: multi-line code is terrible in comments. Adding another answer instead._

Answer (score 0):

Extending on the existing answer from @demarco-glover and suggestion from @axiac.

The `-f` flag in `stat` reports on the filesystem rather than the file itself. So we don't want to use that.

We can get the file size using:

```bash
stat $file1_path | awk '/Size:/{print $2}'
```

Putting that together with the previous answer you would get:

```bash
mv_if_larger () {
    file1_path=$1
    file2_path=$2
    file1_size=$(stat $file1_path | awk '/Size:/{print $2}')
    file2_size=$(stat $file2_path | awk '/Size:/{print $2}')
    if [ "$file1_size" -gt "$file2_size" ]; then
        mv $file1_path $file2_path
    else
        echo "Operation Aborted: \"$file1_path\" is not larger than \"$file2_path\""
    fi
}
```